# Returned generic bounded type incorrect

Tags: java, generics, subtype

Hello I have a return type problem for a generic method that returns a subclass but the compiler thinks it returns the superclass, although I don't know why would that be a problem anyway.

```
  public <T extends SomeEntity> T createOrUpdateWithOwnerId(
      RepositoryContext repoCtx, T entity, String ownerId) throws SomeComponentException {
    return getEntityService(entity.getEntityType())
        .createOrUpdateWithOwnerId(repoCtx, entity, ownerId); //this doesn't compile
```

> Required: T, Provided: SomeEntity

```
  }

public class AuditableEntityService<T extends SomeEntity> {
  public T createOrUpdateWithOwnerId(RepositoryContext repoCtx, T entity, String ownerId)
      throws SomeComponentException {
    try {
      return persistenceRepository.saveOrUpdateWithOwnerId(repoCtx, entity, ownerId);
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
      dealWithRepositoryException(entity, e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

AuditableEntityService<AdminProfile> adminProfileService = new AuditableEntityService<>(new AdminProfile()); // where AdminProfile extends SomeEntity
```

Comment: Please also provide signature of `getEntityService`

Comment: Is `SomeEntity` a generic type? Can you show how `SomeEntity` is declared as well?

Comment: @Sweeper 
`public abstract class SomeEntity extends AuditableBaseEntity {
  public abstract SomeEntityType getEntityType();

  public abstract EntityIdentifiers getIdentifiers();
}
`
AuditableBaseEntity is not genric

Comment: @samabcde
`<T extends SomeEntity> AuditableEntityService<T> getEntityService(SomeEntityType entityType)
      throws SomeComponentException {
    switch (entityType) {
      case ADMIN:
        return (AuditableEntityService<T>) adminProfileService;
      case COUNTRY:
        return (AuditableEntityService<T>) countryService;
      default:
        logger.error("The entity service is not mapped for {}", entityType.getValue());
        throw new SomeComponentException(
            ErrorCode.ENTITY_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND, "general.internal.server");
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding another layer:

```
<T extends SomeEntity> AuditableEntityService<T> getEntityService(T entity)       throws SomeComponentException {
     return getEntityService(entity.getEntityType());   
}
```

Where createOrUpdateWithOwnerId calls the new getEntityService(entity) so the type is the same as the parameter for sure.